# Menu redirects only go to the index.php page with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter is a first for me so I hope I am clear in my explanation. In this case, I am dealing with setting up a Codeigniter website on a different server. I was getting forbidden access errors but have since corrected this, I think.

I've worked out the base url in config file to:

**$config['base_url']   = 'http://websitename.com/';**

and index_page is:

**$config['index_page'] = '';**

with the uri as:

**$config['uri_protocol']   = 'AUTO';**

The links from the menu are not redirecting properly. They simply reload the index page. In Firebug, this is what I see as one of the page links:

**https://websitename.com/index.php?module/rekap_tl**

Perhaps this is enough to understand the trouble here. I am working with this on a live server.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: // Edit .htacess file //  RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase    /project/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: What are the .htaccess settings. Have you put mod rewrite settings to ignore index.php in the URL. For this to work you will also have to ensure mod rewrite is enabled in the Apache/php settings

Comment: My current .htaccess reads as follows:     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /websitename.com/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

you can configure codeigniter like 
`$config['base_url'] = '';` // Leave it empty so that codeigniter can guess it by itself, set `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` and `$config['uri_protocol']   = 'AUTO';` after that open `application/config/autoload.php` and then add url helper class to autoload helper  `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');` after that you can use in you menus `"<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/controller/method/args"` hope this may help

Comment: I don't really understand the last part of your comment there:     after that you can use in you menus "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/controller/method/args"

Comment: I've set the config as you suggested. It shows the url in the header but it's not displaying the proper outcome. The URL's displayed are: https://websitename.com/index.php?module/rekap_tl but index.php is still displayed.

Comment: what is module and rekap_tl can you explain it and why you are using the question marks "?"

Comment: these are modules used to display data from the database which are recorded by a phone application. I am only trying to recreate the site on the new server. I am still familiarizing myself with Codeigniter and it's ways of implementation.

Comment: At i have told you that your link should look like this websitename.come/index.php/controllerName/MethodName/Arguments[Optional] if you specity your url in this format then your code will work

Comment: Hi Mansoor and thank you again. I asked in my earlier comment where I might work that out within Codeigniter. You said "in my menus I can use "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/controller/method/args". Perhaps you can point me in the right direction here. Apologies for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: in the menu area there is currently this string for the URL's:   <? echo site_url('module/'.$Srow->module,$Srow->menu_name);?>

Comment: I have shown you the pattern how the codeigniter work , In your scenario what you will have to do first of all you will have to create a controller and then inside controller you will have to create a method which will get records from database and return it to views. So i have given you a pattern to create a menus like <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/controller/method/arguments">